# opposite byte order to the preceding objects using armcc

Tags: c, linker, fatal-error, endianness, armcc

I'm using `armcc` and `armlink` to compile and link my program. After compiling source codes I tried to link them with `armlink` command, but I got this error:

`Fatal error: ./Release/Source/BookCity/bookcity_Protocol.o has the opposite byte
 order to the preceding objects.`

What does this error means? How can I change byte ordering in `armcc`?

Here is my linking command:

`armlink -bin -o ./cis-0.123.bin ../../Lib/X2API.alf ../../Lib/X2DeviceB.alf ../../Lib/X2Font.alf ../../Lib/X2PPPTCP.alf ./Release/Source/BookCity/bookcity_Protocol.o  ./Release/Source/BookCity/bookcity_configuration.o  ./Release/Source/BookCity/bookcity_initialization.o ./Release/Source/BookCity/bookcity_transactions.o  ./Release/Source/Cash/cash_configuration.o`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your data initialization. From "Writing a Bi-Endian Compiler" :

> **Data Initialization**
>
> In the BEC, pointer data types can also be attributed with a byte
>   order. As a result, there may be situations where a pointer has the
>   opposite byte order as the target platform. Pointers of the opposite
>   byte order must be byte-swapped upon initialization. This presents a
>   challenge when **pointers are initialized by link time constants because
>   these constants are unknown at compile time and are resolved later
>   during the linking stage.**

Source : http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/writing-a-bi-endian-compiler/240003090

If it didn't solve your problem, think about submitting a bug issue to the compiler team dev. It's may be an internal bug.